# Suitable while loop when receiving unknown size in sockets?

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I am currently working on Java <-> C# socket communication. Having read tutorial such as [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server), I notice many tutorials have a similar loop such as;

```
 while (true)
  {
    bytesRead = 0;

    try
    {
      //blocks until a client sends a message
      bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
    }
    catch
    {
      //a socket error has occured
      break;
    }

    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
      //the client has disconnected from the server
      break;
    }

    //message has successfully been received
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
  }

  tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Where `message` is a byte array (buffer).

I often get in to trouble with the `while(true)` loop. My understanding is, as `clientStream.Read` (and its similar counterpart in Java) returns the amount of bytes it has read in to the buffer as an int. So I tend to code the following;

```
int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
stringBuilder.Append(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
Console.WriteLine("Read: " + bytesRead);
while (bytesRead==message.Length)
{
  try
  {
    //blocks until a client sends a message
    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);            
  }
  catch
  {
     //a socket error has occured
     break;
  }
  if (bytesRead == 0)
  {
     //the client has disconnected from the server
     break;
  }
  else
  {
     stringBuilder.Append(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Read: " + bytesRead);
}
```

You will notice that my I have changed my while to `while (bytesRead==message.Length)`. I changed the loop so that it will only enter it if the my buffer is full (so there is more data to read) and will remain in the loop until it has read an amount of bytes that is less that the maximum the buffer can hold.

When I run my version, I don't seem to get hanging issues which I had when using the methods found in the tutorials. Am I overlooking anything? Will my method eventually cause any errors which I can't notice?

Comment: this should be placed at:http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ i think

Comment: Ok, if others agree I shall move it there! :)

Comment: The original code with `while(true)` is in fact more elegant, imho, as it calls `Read()` and `Append()` in one place only. Don't Repeat Yourself.